# Which graph databases can do ad-hoc queries?

Tags: nosql, graph-databases

By ad-hoc, I mean queries that can drill down to every property of the data.

Queries such as,

- fetch all nodes where type=persion and age between 20 and 30
- any node whose tag is [funny,adorable]
- name starts with Se*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [Neo4j](http://neo4j.org) you can use the query language [Cypher](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypher-query-lang.html) to express such ad-hoc queries, either with the built-in console of the web-admin tool, via the embedded Java, JRuby or Python-API or via the remote REST-API which has drivers in many languages.

Some examples:

```
start p=node:types(type='person') where p.age > 20 and p.age < 30 return p
start p=node:node_auto_index("id:*") where p.name =~ /Se.*/ return p
start p=node(0) match r-[:TAG]->tag where tag.name = 'funny' or tag.name = 'adorable' return tag
```